# Consulta com LINQ, tentando realizar um RIGHT JOIN

Tags: c#, linq

Preciso fazer a seguinte consulta através do LINQ, usando as tabelas informadas:

Deve retornar todos os veículos onde o "Tipo" tenha o campo "PARTE" igual a "true", a ligação da tabela "Veiculo" com a tabela "Tipo" é feita através da tabela "Modelo", porem se o veículo já foi atrelado a tabela "Conjunto" ele também não deve ser exibido.

Neste caso eu preciso retornar os veículos com ID 51, 66 e 72

```
Veiculo
-----------------
ID PLACA   IDMODELO
49 AAA0001 13
50 AAA0002 13
51 AAA0003 15
65 AAA0004 19
66 AAA0005 14
71 AAA0006 13
72 AAA0007 19


Modelo
-----------------
ID MODELO   IDTIPO
13 Reboque  22
14 Caminhão 27
15 Carreta  28
19 Bitrem   27


Tipo
-----------------
ID TIPO PARTE
22 V1   false
27 V2   true
28 R1   true


Conjunto
-----------------
IDVEICULOCONJUNTO IDVEICULO
50                65
```

Tentei realizar a seguinte consulta:

```
from vei in dc.Veiculo
join mod in dc.ModeloVeiculo on vei.IdModeloVeiculo equals mod.IdModeloVeiculo
join tiv in dc.TipoVeiculo on mod.IdTipoVeiculo equals tiv.IdTipoVeiculo
join vec in dc.VeiculoConjunto on vei.IdVeiculo equals vec.IdVeiculo into jData
from jvei in jData.DefaultIfEmpty()
where tiv.ParteConjunto.Equals(true) &&
    (jvei == null || (idVeiculo == 0 || jvei.IdVeiculo == idVeiculo))
select vei
```

mas ele retornar os IDs 51, 65, 65 e 72

Comment: Já tentas-te fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: O que você já fez até o momento? Está dando erro? Qual?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o que eu havia testado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi a questão da seguinte forma:

```
from vei in dc.Veiculo
join mod in dc.ModeloVeiculo on vei.IdModeloVeiculo equals mod.IdModeloVeiculo
join tiv in dc.TipoVeiculo on mod.IdTipoVeiculo equals tiv.IdTipoVeiculo
join vec in dc.VeiculoConjunto on vei.IdVeiculo equals vec.IdVeiculo into jData
from jvei in jData.DefaultIfEmpty()
where tiv.ParteConjunto.Equals(true) &&
    (jvei == null || (idVeiculo != 0 && jvei.IdVeiculo == idVeiculo))
select vei
```